# masking php fsockopen client

Tags: php, websocket

I have a websocket server running by PHP using `socket_create().`
I am using following code :

```
function customError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)  { 
    $theerror= "Error [$errno] in $errfile on line $errline : $errstr ";    
    $errorlogfile = fopen(date("d_m_y")."socket.log", "a"); 
    fwrite($errorlogfile, PHP_EOL.date("h:i:s").' - '.$theerror);
    fclose($errorlogfile);
}

set_error_handler("customError");

function wmlog($log){
    $f=fopen(date("d_m_y").'socket.log','a');
    fwrite($f, $log." \r\n ");
    fclose($f);
}

$wmdir=dirname(__FILE__);

$host = 'srvdb';
$port = $argv[1];
/* $ccode=$argv[4];
$uid=$argv[3] ;
$cid=$argv[4];  */
$null = NULL;    //host

if(!$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP){
    wmlog("ERROR creating socket") ;
}else{
    wmlog("socket created") ;
}

socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);//reuseable port

socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);//bind socket to specified host
socket_listen($socket);//listen to port
$clients = array($socket);//create & add listning socket to the list
include_once($wmdir.'/intochat_f.php');
//include_once($wmdir.'/include1.php');
wmlog("included") ;
//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {//manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);//returns the socket resources in $changed array

///////// AD NEW SOCKET ///////
// $a_pv - passed values  ()
if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {//check for new socket
    $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
    $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
    $a_h=explode(PHP_EOL, $header);
    $s_get=$a_h[0];
    unset($a_h[0]) ;
    $a_header=array();
    foreach($a_h as $v){
        $nk=strtok($v, ":");
        $nv=substr($v, (strrpos($v, ':') ?: -1) +1);
        $a_header[$nk]=$nv;
    }
    $a_pv=explode('_', $s_get);
    $a_pv[0] = $a_header['Sec-WebSocket-Protocol'];
    $pid=$a_pv[1];    
    $clients[$pid] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array
    wmlog('HEADER: '. " \r\n ". $header. " \r\n EOF HEADER ");
    perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

    wmlog((socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip))." ip: ".$ip. "\r\n")  ; //get ip address of connected socket
    //$response = mask(json_encode(array('act2'=>30))); //prepare json data
    //send_message($response, $pid); //notify all users about new connection

    //make room for new socket
    $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
    unset($changed[$found_socket]);
}

//loop through all connected sockets
foreach ($changed as $socketid => $changed_socket) {    

    //check for any incomming data and do smth with it 
    while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)     {
        $received_text = unmask($buf);
        $msg = json_decode($received_text);//unmask data  AND json decode 
        // PUT MESSAGE TO DB ////


        /// SEND MESSAGE TO OTHERS (priv or everybody )/// 
        if(isset($msg->to) && $msg->to >0 ){
            $scopeid=$msg->to;
        }else{
            $scopeid=0;
        } 
        //$a_response=$msg.
        //prepare data to be sent to client
        $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('val1'=>$msg->val1, 'val2'=>$msg->val2, 'from'=>$socketid )));
        send_message($response_text, $scopeid); //send data
        break 2; //exist this loop
    }

    $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
    if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
        // remove client for $clients array
        $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
        socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
        unset($clients[$found_socket]);

        //notify all users about disconnected connection
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('val1'=>'somebody left', 'val2'=>' left user')));
        send_message($response);
    }
}
}

socket_close($socket);

function send_message($msg, $id=0){
    global $clients;
    if($id==0){ // send message to everybody
        foreach($clients as $changed_socket){
            @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
        }
    }else{ // send message to selected socket 
        @socket_write($clients[$id],$msg,strlen($msg));
    }

    return true;
}

function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }else{
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }

    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

function mask($text){
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);
    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port) {
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches)){
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header

    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";

    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}
```

If I use connect to it from browser (using javascript `new WebSocket(wsUri);` ) - it works fine, but when I try to connect to it from PHP script using `fsockopen()`, data after unmasking looks gibberish but like valid JSON before unmasking.

And the question is - why is unmasking not working when sending data via PHP `fsockopen` / how to make it work?

Comment: and, what is your question?

Comment: I did some basic formatting to your code block. The easiest way to format a code block on SO is to paste your code, then select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button. This indents the whole block by an additional four spaces, instructing Stack Overflow to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

I found by google in one forum this ([tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.1)):

> A server MUST NOT mask any frames that it sends to the client.
> A client MUST close a connection if it detects a masked
> frame.